# Integer solutions to $7^a + 1 = 2^b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for integer solutions to the equation $7^a + 1 = 2^b$. There are two obvious answers:

- $a=0, b=1$
- $a=1, b=3$

I believe that those are the *only* solutions, but I am unable to prove it. I have made some amount of progress considering methods for finding divisors ($\ne 2$) for given $7^a+1$ $(a \ge 2)$, i.e.:

$m \ne 2 : 7^a \equiv -1 \mod m$

For instance, for $a = 2$, we can find that

$7^2 \equiv 4 \equiv -1 \mod 5 \implies 5 |(7^2+1) \implies \not \exists b : 7^2+1 = 2^b$

Also, since $Ord_5(7) = 4$, we know that $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z^*}, 7^{2+4k} \equiv -1 \mod 5$. For each $a$ up to 16 or so, I have been able to come up with an $m$ like that, but I have no general proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider powers of $7 \bmod 16$. These are alternately equal to $1$ and $7$.

Therefore $7^a+1 = (2+16k$ or $8+16k)$. These can only be powers of $2$ when $k=0$.

Comment: Nice and compact solution!

Comment: Thank your for your solution. Would you say that a good general strategy for problems like this would be to consider taking the expression mod powers of the other base (e.g., taking $7^a+1$ mod powers of 2 in this case) and looking for simplifications?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete yes, both ways round can often be useful.

Answer (score 5):

It is clear that $a$ and $b$ must be non-negative. Let $a$ be even; then $7^a+1\equiv 2\pmod{8}$. Thus the only candidate for $b$ is $b=1$. That yields the solution $a=0$.

Now let $a$ be odd. Then $7^a+1$ factors as $(7+1)(7^{a-1}-7^{a-2}+\cdots +1)$. Note that $7^{a-1}-7^{a-2}+\cdots +1$  is odd. Thus the only $b$ that works is $b=3$.

**Remark:** If we want to hit the problem with a very large hammer, we can use [Mihailescu's Theorem (once known as the Catalan Conjecture).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture)

Comment: Thank your for your solution. Would you say that a good general strategy for problems like this would be to consider taking the expression mod powers of the other base (e.g., taking $7^a+1$ mod powers of 2 in this case) and looking for simplifications?

Comment: What you suggest is a sensible way to proceed, particularly in "assigned problems." However, many simple-looking exponential Diophantine equations do not succumb to simple congruential arguments.

Comment: That is a very big hammer indeed :-)